# What is the refresh frequency of AdControl in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I just added AdControl to my app, and want to frequently change ads on it.

So I set IsAutoRefreshEnabled = True.  But I cannot find detailed information about how frequently the adds will be changed.

Can someone help me with this question, please?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer.

After 1 min. of showing ad a request for another ad is send, and when the new ad is downloaded it is shown. Usualy abouth 1-1,5 min when IsAutoRefreshEnabled set to "True"

Hope it helps :)